# Vagrant halt is failing with _syntax error near unexpected token `||'_

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

**Vagrant is not able to halt / reload** after the initial vagrant up (ie the one where the vm is provisioned). The initial vagrant up completes correctly, however after that I am not able to do the vagrant halt or reload.

```
The error message that I am getting is 

==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

shutdown -h now

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
bash: line 2: `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=                ||     ||'
```

List of vagrant plugin I am using
 - vagrant-proxyconf (1.5.2) 
 - vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)

Vagrant version is 1.8.1
Virtualbox [provider] version 4.3.34r104062
Host OS : Windows 7 Enterprise

I have tried re-installing, all the components, destroying the VMs, deleting the config files [ie ~/.VirtualBox & ~/.vagrant.d]

Please help me in resolving the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fix.

The error went away when I again downloaded the code base from github.